# Change Windows Server 2008 R2 Full to Server Core

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is it possible (unofficially of course) to *downgrade* a normal Windows Server 2008 R2 installation to Server Core. Which is theoretically speaking just a trimmed down version of the normal interactive version.

Anybody done it? **How?**

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  You will need to reinstall the OS.

Technically it is possible, but Microsoft never bothered to spend the money or manhours to implement such a niche feature. I, for one, am glad.

Plus, for a Server install, I wouldn't trust the process **even if they did implement it**. There are just way too many test cases to consider and test, too many for a company even like Microsoft to cover.

Comment: I totally understand your argument here. I just though that installing server software is easier in normal version, then just trim it down for production later. I was just setting up a dev machine with Win Web Server 2k8 R2 and SQL Express 2008 R2. This is of course possible to be ran in core mode (since R2 it is because it includes .net)...

Comment: They have now changed it for Server 2012.